# Tyk Custom Authentication Plugin with .NET do not work with POST request

Tags: c#, .net-core, tyk

I made a Tyk plugin to do a custom authentication checking. Follow this URL: https://tyk.io/docs/customise-tyk/plugins/rich-plugins/grpc/custom-auth-dot-net/

But it's working with GET request and not POST.
The body is removed after go through Tyk. So it's always NULL when it come to server.
Any idea or special setup in Tyk that i need?

Answer (score 1):

It's working after upgrade Grpc; Google.Protobuf and re-generate Coprocess
The current versions working:
Google.Protobuf 3.7.0
Grpc 1.19.0

It was an issue with:
Google.Protobuf 3.4.0
Grpc 1.6.0